# unsatisfiable cycle and "ObjectIdInput" related exception in Quarkus GraphQL

Tags: mongodb, quarkus, graphql-java, quarkus-panache

I am developing a project with Quarkus and mongodb. I have a model as below.

```
@MongoEntity(collection = "Designation")
public class Designation extends ReactivePanacheMongoEntityBase {

    @AdaptToScalar(Scalar.String.class)
    public ObjectId id;

    @NotBlank(message = "Name must not be blank")
    public String name;
    @NotBlank(message = "Short name must not be blank")
    public String shortName;
    @NotBlank(message = "Grade must not be blank")
    public Integer grade;
   
    public Designation bn;
}
```

The model has two parts, name,shortName, grade are for English language, and **bn** is for **Bangla** language and it's of type **Designation** as it has the same properties like name, shortName and grade.

I have a graphql resource as below.

```
@GraphQLApi
public class DesignationGResource {

    @Query("designations")
    @Description("Get all designations")
    public Uni<List<Designation>> getAllDesignations(){
        return Designation.listAll();
    }

    @Query("designation")
    @Description("Get designation by id")
    public Uni<Designation> getDesignationById(@Name("designationId") String designationId){
        return Designation.findById(new ObjectId(designationId));
    }

    @Mutation
    public Uni<Designation> saveDesignation(Designation designation){
        return designation.persist();
    }
}
```

Here *Query* is working fine. But the **saveDesignation()** mutation is not working and throwing two exceptions, one for **ObjectId: "ObjectIdInput" must define one or more fields** and one for **unsatisfiable cycle: [bn!] forms an unsatisfiable cycle** and the full exception message is shown here:

```
Caused by: graphql.schema.validation.InvalidSchemaException: invalid schema:
[bn!] forms an unsatisfiable cycle
"ObjectIdInput" must define one or more fields.
    at graphql.schema.GraphQLSchema$Builder.validateSchema(GraphQLSchema.java:828)
    at graphql.schema.GraphQLSchema$Builder.buildImpl(GraphQLSchema.java:822)
    at graphql.schema.GraphQLSchema$Builder.build(GraphQLSchema.java:787)
    at io.smallrye.graphql.bootstrap.Bootstrap.generateGraphQLSchema(Bootstrap.java:186)
    at io.smallrye.graphql.bootstrap.Bootstrap.bootstrap(Bootstrap.java:113)
    at io.smallrye.graphql.bootstrap.Bootstrap.bootstrap(Bootstrap.java:107)
    at io.smallrye.graphql.cdi.producer.GraphQLProducer.initialize(GraphQLProducer.java:34)
    at io.smallrye.graphql.cdi.producer.GraphQLProducer_Subclass.initialize$$superforward1(Unknown Source)
    at io.smallrye.graphql.cdi.producer.GraphQLProducer_Subclass$$function$$2.apply(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:54)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.proceed(InvocationInterceptor.java:62)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.monitor(InvocationInterceptor.java:51)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:32)
    at io.smallrye.graphql.cdi.producer.GraphQLProducer_Subclass.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at io.smallrye.graphql.cdi.producer.GraphQLProducer.initialize(GraphQLProducer.java:29)
    at io.smallrye.graphql.cdi.producer.GraphQLProducer_Subclass.initialize$$superforward1(Unknown Source)
    at io.smallrye.graphql.cdi.producer.GraphQLProducer_Subclass$$function$$4.apply(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:54)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.proceed(InvocationInterceptor.java:62)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.monitor(InvocationInterceptor.java:51)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:32)
    at io.smallrye.graphql.cdi.producer.GraphQLProducer_Subclass.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at io.smallrye.graphql.cdi.producer.GraphQLProducer.initialize(GraphQLProducer.java:24)
    at io.smallrye.graphql.cdi.producer.GraphQLProducer_Subclass.initialize$$superforward1(Unknown Source)
    at io.smallrye.graphql.cdi.producer.GraphQLProducer_Subclass$$function$$3.apply(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:54)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.proceed(InvocationInterceptor.java:62)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.monitor(InvocationInterceptor.java:51)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:32)
    at io.smallrye.graphql.cdi.producer.GraphQLProducer_Subclass.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at io.smallrye.graphql.cdi.producer.GraphQLProducer_ClientProxy.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.smallrye.graphql.runtime.SmallRyeGraphQLRecorder.createExecutionService(SmallRyeGraphQLRecorder.java:31)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.SmallRyeGraphQLProcessor$buildExecutionService259019385.deploy_1(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.SmallRyeGraphQLProcessor$buildExecutionService259019385.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:347)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:645)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:66)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:120)
    at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.StartupActionImpl$1.run(StartupActionImpl.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Currently, I am handling the mutation using below code.

```
    @Mutation("createDesignation")
    @Description("Create designation")
    public Uni<Designation> createDesignation(String name,String shortName,Integer grade,String bnName,String bnShortName){
        Designation designation = new Designation();
        designation.name = name;
        designation.shortName = shortName;
        designation.grade = grade;
        designation.bn  = new Designation();
        designation.bn.name = bnName;
        designation.bn.shortName = bnShortName;
        return designation.persist();
    }
```

But is there any way to handle the above **ObjectId** and **unsatisfiable cycle** exception?

Comment: Any update on this. I was asked to try adaptor and it works for query but not for mutation.

Comment: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/24716 Following the issue with @phillip on quarkus discussions.

Comment: @Doogle, thanks for mentioning the issue in the Quarkus GitHub issue section.

Comment: Finally after debugging we get the root cause.
This is a smallrye bug and will be resolved there soon. Keep a track of the ticket. https://github.com/smallrye/smallrye-graphql/issues/1342